# Adjacent figures in latex and pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, psfrag

I use psfragfig along with matlabfrag for substituting figure texts, labels in Latex font. It works very well. Recently I switched for organizational purposes to use latex compiler instead of pdflatex that I used to work before.

I want two pictures adjacent to each other and I am getting this weird behavior now while compiled from latex:[image]

And the same figure compiled with pdflatex: [image]

The code for them is

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\psfragfig[width=0.45\textwidth]{./pics/cd0_90vsRe}
\psfragfig[width=0.45\textwidth]{./pics/logcd0_90}
\end{figure}
```

Even the same pictures at much smaller size still appear top-bottom on compiling with latex. Can someone let me know how to fix this issue for latex?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was fixed with the use of `subfloat` from the `subfig` package.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat{\psfragfig[width=0.45\textwidth]{./pics/cd0_90vsRe}}
\subfloat{\psfragfig[width=0.45\textwidth]{./pics/logcd0_90}}
\end{figure}
```

However, I do not know the reason for formatting difference between `latex` and `pdflatex` compilers, how small the figures be.